# Show that the integral of this rational function is equal to an infinite alternating harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

One of my friends gave me the following question from his review, I have little experience to dealing with these types of questions in Analysis so if you could help us just to get started it would be quite helpful.

> Rigorously justify the following:
>   $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

Comment: @Argon , you should write down your comment as an answer. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Done, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** A geometric series gives 
$$ {1\over 1+x^2}={1\over 1-(-x^2)}=\lim_N \sum_{n=0}^N (-x^2)^n.$$

To be more precise, for the alternating series show
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{2N+1} (-x^2)^n\leq {1\over 1+x^2}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{2N} (-x^2)^n,\tag1$$
then integrate through (1).

Comment: Since the above works when $|x|<1$, then we integrate to obtain, $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\lim_N\sum_{n=0}^N(-x^2)^n$, so if we manage to interchange the limit and the sum we are game, but I am very rusty at analysis, and I dont remember why this interchange is allowed.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre I've added another step that might help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\arctan(a)=\int_0^a \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n a^{2n+1}} {2n+1}$$

so

$$\arctan(1) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n} {2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$